# Performance hit when using Entity Framework log redirected to NLog

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nlog

in my web service (Web API 2, C#) I use NLog as logging library and it works ok. Impact on performance is minimal when 5 to 10 lines per request are logged. However, I wanted to get a view on the Entity Framework behaviour and therefore I coupled the ***dbcontext.Dabase.Log*** to a function that writes the EF output to the same log file. Though it works nicely, I also see suddenly my requests take almost double the time they needed before: 1200ms instead of the previous 600ms, so that is 600ms extra for writing extra 180 lines of logging.

Even though EF logs a multitude of lines, it still surprises me that this takes so much time to write to a simple file. I don't use any special configuration in NLog, just write everything to a file, without any filtering. Any hints appreciated.

Kind regards,

Wim

Comment: Run your code under the profiler and see that actually take time. You might be wrong that it is Nlog itself. Maybe logging inside the function you introduce add extra time. As alternative, you may replace the logging in your function to fixed line and see if there's any difference.

Comment: See the help center: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Nevertheless: log4net.

Comment: I actually commented out the NLog line in the code and that's why I saw the difference and why I'm sure it is in the NLog code that the delay is happening. It's not some other code that generating this kind of delay...

Answer (score 3):

One hint could be to use the `AsyncWrapper` target 
something like the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
        <!-- Log in a separate thread, possibly queueing up to
        5000 messages. When the queue overflows, discard any
        extra messages-->

        <target name="file" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper" queueLimit="5000" overflowAction="Discard">
            <target xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${level}.txt" />
        </target>
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

**Note**
that if you write more then 5000 messages in a short time you may lose some messages so you have to increase the `queueLimit` as more as you need.

From [Nlog wiki](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/AsyncWrapper-target)

> Asynchronous target wrapper allows the logger code to execute more
>   quickly, by queuing messages and processing them in a separate thread.
>   You should wrap targets that spend a non-trivial amount of time in
>   their Write() method with asynchronous target to speed up logging.

Comment: Ok, thx for the answer. Don't know why my post is being put on hold since this seems like legit question on an often used component that others might profit off when running into the same experiences.
I will try your suggestion today and see what happens. One side effect of async writing might be that a unhandled "crash" of the application might destroy the queue so log information is lost at that point

Comment: I have edited your question.  you should not ask  for an alternative library because it's not the goal of stackoverflow

Comment: Also note that the async wrapper not only writes to the target in another thread, but it also writes in batches which could improve the performance.

Comment: The async wrapper indeeds keeps the execution time low and constant. Thank you very much for the tip! The fact that in case of a crash the logging is gone will have to be taken into account that ... but that's not that big of a problem in this scenario....